# Swift: Generics to typecast baseProtocol to child protocols

Tags: swift, oop, generics, protocols

VC = ViewController

VM = ViewModel

P = Protocol

I have ViewModel protocols & classes in the format

```
protocol BaseVMP {
}
protocol VM1P: BaseVMP {
}
protocol VM2P: BaseVMP {
}

class BaseVM: BaseVMP {
}
class VM1: BaseVM, VM1P {
}
class VM2: BaseVM, VM2P {
}

ViewController classes
class BaseVC {
    var baseVM: BaseVMP
}

class VC1: BaseVC {
    var vm: VM1P
}
class VC2: BaseVC {
    var vm: VM2P
}
```

As of now, I am keeping 2 variables for viewModel, one as vm and another one as baseVM in VC & baseVC respectively. What I want to achieve is that I keep just one variable vm in BaseVC which gets typecasted (if this is the correct term, I hope you got the meaning) to VM1P/VM2P when I want to access it in VC1/VC2. Is it possible with the help of generics?

Answer (score 1):

With your class hierarchy you can have your BaseVC, VC1, VC2, structure something like,

```
class BaseVC<T:BaseVMP> {
    var vm: T
    init(vm: T) {
        self.vm = vm
    }
}

class VC1<T: VM1P>: BaseVC<T> {

}

class VC2<T: VM2P>: BaseVC<T> {

}

let vc1 = VC1(vm: VM1())
let vc2 = VC2(vm: VM2())
```

Note, vm property is inherited in all the subclasses and for VC1 and VC2, they are of specific types VM1 and VM2. I hope this is what you were looking for.

By the way, you should either have initializer or make property implicitly unwrapped just so that there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

You already have that, BaseVMP can both hold an instance of VM1P and VM2P since they both comply to BaseVMP protocol.

```
class BaseVC
{
    var baseVM: BaseVMP! // Be sure that's initialized before use.
}

class VC1: BaseVC
{
    func setVM(vm: BaseVMP)
    {
        baseVM = vm as! VM1P // VM1P implements BaseVMP
    }
}
```